# Converting files to UTF-8 without BOM in ANT

Tags: encoding, utf-8, ant, byte-order-mark

I have some js files that are in `UTF-8 BOM` encoding. I want to convert these files to `UTF-8` encoding using ant. I used `copy` task of ant for this

```
<copy todir="./custom_plugins" overwrite="true" outputencoding="UTF-8">
    <fileset dir="../plugins" />
</copy>
```

Now when I open a file that was in `UTF-8 BOM` in notepad++ it shows its encoding in `ANSI` format but this also appends the `ï»¿` character at the beginning of the file.

Even i tried [this](http://www.petervannes.nl/files/8a3dc052af5b97364e0ad13054e3b318-48.php), but not working.
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After encoding these files to `UTF-8` I used `replaceregexp` ant task to remove/replace BOM character `\xEF\xBB\xBF` with empty string.

```
<replaceregexp match="\xEF\xBB\xBF" replace="" byline="true" encoding="UTF-8">
    <fileset dir="./custom_plugins">
        <include name="**/*.js"/>
    </fileset>
</replaceregexp>
```